# Can we have syntax highlighting?

Tags: feature-request

It seems that language syntax highlighting is not working.

As I think we will have many answers involving small code fragments. Is it possible to enable this?

Few examples: [1](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/63/191), [2](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/124/191).

I used `<!-- language: lang-... -->` to specify the language in both cases.

Comment: Yes, and it should be auto-enabled for questions being tagged with a programming languages, like on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I thought this kind of feature would be automatically enabled by the stackexchange engine. It would be a nice addition to have it. Readability counts.

Comment: I've asked SE to activate this and they just told me they have. It should be live soon (there might be some caching issues involved).

Comment: @KonradRudolph that can be set up by mods. The tag page a mod sees also has an option to associate a tag with a language.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I mentioned this to an SE employee and they implemented it today! We now have working syntax highlighting!

Tags can have a specific language syntax associated with them. This is something that mods can set up. So, for example, if we were to ever have a [perl](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perl) or, more likely a [bioperl](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioperl) tag, the mods could set it up so that it is associated with Perl syntax highlighting.

If a question isn't tagged with a tag that is associated with any specific syntax highlighting, we can still enable it using HTML comments. The syntax is as follows (using `perl` as an example):

```
<!-- language: lang-perl -->
```

Each code block you want to have highlighted must have a comment like the one above, an empty line, and then the code. For example, this:

```
<!-- language: lang-python -->

    var="foo"
```

Will be rendered like this:

```python
import foo
var="bar"
otherVar = None
```

Each code block in a question or answer needs its own HTML comment, and you need a blank line between the comment and the first line of code, as shown above. Here's the list of currently supported languages and their identifying string (the `lang` prefix is not needed if a tag has the language associated with it, but it won't harm it and we're unlikely to have many such tags anyway):

```
none:      none   ## Useful for disabling syntax highlighting
bash:      lang-bash OR lang-bsh
c:         lang-c
clj:       lang-clj
coffee:    lang-coffee
cpp:       lang-cpp
cs:        lang-cs
csh:       lang-csh
css:       lang-css
dart:      lang-dart
erlang:    lang-erlang
go:        lang-go
hs:        lang-hs
html:      lang-html
java:      lang-java
js:        lang-js
latex:     lang-latex
lisp:      lang-lisp
lua:       lang-lua
ml:        lang-ml
pascal:    lang-pascal
perl:      lang-perl
php:       lang-php
proto:     lang-proto
py:        lang-py
r:         lang-r
rb:        lang-rb
regex:     lang-regex
rust:      lang-rust
scala:     lang-scala
sh:        lang-sh
sql:       lang-sql
vb:        lang-vb
vhdl:      lang-vhdl
xml:       lang-xml
```

Comment: Did this stop working? I can’t seem to get anything highlighted, see e.g. here: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/69/29 (both tagged, and the code is explicitly marked with a language).

Comment: @KonradRudolph no, it works, it's just not very helpful for the code you posted. The snippet you had explicitly set a language for was colored but only in the words `function` and the `1E6` of `log(1E6)`. The one you hadn't set explicitly wasn't colored because I hadn't associated the tag `R` with a language for syntax highlighting. I have now done so, so any future posts won't need the explicit `<!-- language: lang-r -->` anymore.

Comment: Right, I forgot how … err … *minimal* Stack Overflow’s syntax highlighting is. Bit bizarre, given that programming languages is their core competence.

Comment: @KonradRudolph AFAIK, they just use something developed by Google. And it does work OK for many cases. R doesn't seem to be one of them though, granted.